# Задача на ассинхронность

Tags: javascript, async-await

Даны 3 асинхронные функции со случайным setTimeout
Нужно написать код, который выведет в консоль:
A
B
C

```
function foo(callback) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    callback("A");
  }, Math.random() * 100);
}

function bar(callback) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    callback("B");
  }, Math.random() * 100);
}

function baz(callback) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    callback("C");
  }, Math.random() * 100);
}
```

Comment: я полагаю это JavaScript... Укажите это в метках. Также было бы неплохо услышать ваши мысли по поводу данной задачи и узнать где и в чем именно у вас возникла сложность

Comment: я пытался решить данную задачу, используя объект Promise: в методе then вызывать эти функции по цепочке: Promise.resolve()
  .then(() => foo(console.log))
  .then(() => bar(console.log))
  .then(() => baz(console.log)); К сожалению, такой код не выводит A, B, C строго в такой последовательности. В этом и заключается сложность

Comment: Вообще, эту задачу можно решить таким способом:    foo((callback) => {
  console.log(callback);
  bar((callback) => {
    console.log(callback);
    baz((callback) => {
      console.log(callback);
    });
  });
});    Но хотелось бы без вложенности callback-ов обойтись

Answer (score 4):

Для последовательного выполнения асинхронных функций нужно составить цепочку `Promise`.

Для этого можно добавить функцию, которая вернет `Promise`, разрешающийся, в момент вызова callback

```
function promisify(func) {
  return new Promise(r => func(r));
}
```

после этого, достаточно передавать в нее нужную функцию, составляя цепочку:

```
promisify(foo)
  .then(r => console.log(r))
  .then(() => promisify(bar))
  .then(r => console.log(r))
  .then(() => promisify(baz))
  .then(r => console.log(r))
```

Пример:

```js
function foo(callback) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    callback("A");
  }, Math.random() * 1000);
}

function bar(callback) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    callback("B");
  }, Math.random() * 500);
}

function baz(callback) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    callback("C");
  }, Math.random() * 500);
}

function promisify(func) {
  return new Promise(r => func(r));
}

promisify(foo)
  .then(r => console.log(r))
  .then(() => promisify(bar))
  .then(r => console.log(r))
  .then(() => promisify(baz))
  .then(r => console.log(r))
```

Comment: `Promise.all([promisify(foo), promisify(bar), promisify(baz)]).then(arr => arr.forEach(v => console.log(v))` =)

Comment: @AlexeyTen, как правило в задачах на очередность, подразумевается и очередность выполнения. Здесь, это явно не указано

Answer (score -1):

Замечательное решение от Grundy. Очень короткое и простое.
Но я хотел бы свое привести, более громозкое и сумбурное.

Сначала foo, bar, baz заменим одной функцией f:

```
function f(s, cb) {
    setTimeout(_ => cb(s), Math.random() * 100);
}
```

Попробуем вызвать их друг за другом:

```
f("A", console.log);
f("B", console.log);
f("C", console.log);
```

Получим случайный ответ, например, CAB
Исправим это, сделав вложенные вызовы "пирамидкой":

```
f("A", s => { 
    console.log(s); 
    f("B", s => {
        console.log(s);
        f("C", s => {
            console.log(s);
        })
    })
});
```

Получили правильный ответ, но хотим "выпрямить" код в плоский.
Для начала преобразуем f в промис:

```
let f1 = promisify(f);
function promisify(f) {
    return function(...args) {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            function cb(res) {
                resolve(res);
            }
            args.push(cb);
            f.call(this, ...args);
        });
    }
}
```

Код взят [отсюда](https://learn.javascript.ru/promisify), если вам promisify не нужна, можно сразу сделать замену f:

```
let f1 = function(s) {
    return new Promise(resolve => f(s, () => resolve(s)));
}
```

Либо можно повторить код f:

```
function f1(s) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setInterval(resolve(s), Math.random() * 100));
}
```

Выбор за вами, как вы сделаете функцию, возвращающую промис. Теперь можно воспользоваться await:

```
(async function() {
    await f1("A").then(r => console.log(r));
    await f1("B").then(r => console.log(r));
    await f1("C").then(r => console.log(r));
})();
```

Получаем ABC и вложенностей нет

Не хотите async/await, можно обойтись одним then:

```
f1("A")
    .then(r => console.log(r))
    .then(() => f1("B"))
    .then(r => console.log(r))
    .then(() => f1("C"))
    .then(r => console.log(r));
```

Также был предложен вариант запуска в параллель:

```
Promise.all([f2("A"), f2("B"), f2("C")]).then(rs => rs.forEach(r => console.log(r)));
```

Еще раз отмечу, что использовать асинхронность напрямую с обычными функциями (не возращающих промис) не получится. Их надо либо переписать через промис или промисифицировать (см. выше)

Comment: Не хватает версии с Promise.all. В задаче нужно *вывести* ответ в определённом порядке, а последовательного выполнения не требуется.

Comment: Несмотря на минусы, я оставлю свое решение. Очень надеюсь, что оно кому-то поможет в понимании промисов (с ними не все так просто). Ну либо взять решения от Alexey Ten или Grundy - они универсальные и простые (для тех кто понимает)

Answer (score -2):

Поскольку эта задача явно теоретическая и не имеет практического смысла, то решение тоже теоретическое, но рабочее

```js
function foo(callback) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    callback("A");
  }, Math.random() * 100);
}

function bar(callback) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    callback("B");
  }, Math.random() * 100);
}

function baz(callback) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    callback("C");
  }, Math.random() * 100);
}

window.setTimeout = function(func, timeout) {
    func();
}

foo(console.log);
bar(console.log);
baz(console.log);
```